# string.atChar(0) crashes

Tags: android, string, android-studio

I have an array `koal` of strings with "00" at `koal[0]` but this attempt to get 1st
element from first string crashes:

`tv6.setText(koal[0].charAt(0));`

On the other hand:
`tv6.setText(koal[0])` prints "00".

Why? Or, how do I get ith element from `koal[0]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`charAt()` returns a `char`, which is a numeric type that is then coerced to an `int`, meaning that you're accidentally calling the overload of `setText()` that expects to be passed an `R.string` resource id.

If you want to use the overload of `setText()` that accepts a string, you'll have to manually convert that `char` to a string somehow. One very easy way is to use string concatenation:

```
tv6.setText("" + koal[0].charAt(0));
```

Of course, there are many ways to convert `char` to `String`; this is just the easiest.